# Was Daenerys' baby really stillborn?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Did anyone read or see anything that might suggest that Daenerys' baby was not stillborn but was taken away to be raised by another since he was to be strong and a leader? There was never a sighting of this child and I wonder in the future books if this is ever brought up again or were her statements factual about his death. Also I know she had to kill her husband but I am disappointed he will not be in future seasons. A great couple!

Comment: *"When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east," said Mirri Maz Duur. "When the seas go dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves. When your womb quickens again, and you bear a living child. Then he will return, and not before."*

Answer (score 30):

This plot was not explored as deeply in the series as in the book, and it is less clear to the viewer exactly what was going on.

Essentially, Mirri Maz Duur tricked Dany into using Blood Magic to save Drogo's life, at the cost of her baby's life ("Only death may pay for life").

Khal Drogo collapsed, and Mirri told Dany of a blood magic spell she could use which could save Drogo's life. She told Dany that the price for this spell was death, and misled Dany to believe that killing Drogo's horse would be the "death" that the spell required.

Mirri then begins the spell, and many of the Dothraki freak out and start fighting each other; with many of them leaving. While the spell ritual is still happening, Dany experiences painful convulsions.

> It felt as if her son had a knife in each hand, as if he were hacking at her to cut his way out.

The remaining Dothraki decide to take her to Mirri, as all the "birthing women" have left. Dany suspects at this point that Mirri has betrayed her, and doesn't want to be taken to her; but is in a lot of pain, and is unable to communicate this, so the Dothraki take her to Mirri.

In Dany's next chapter, she wakes up after a bunch of fever-dreams. When she asks about her child, a handmaid tells her that "the boy... he did not live". The next couple of paragraphs essentially confirms the baby's death:

> My son is dead, she thought as Jhiqui left the tent. She had known somehow. She had known since she woke the first time to Jhiqui's tears. No, she had known before she woke. Her dream came back to her, sudden and vivid, and she remembered the tall man with the copper skin and long silver-gold braid, bursting into flame.
>   She should weep, she knew, yet her eyes were dry as ash. She had wept in her dream, and the tears had turned to steam on her cheeks. All the grief has been burned out of me, she told herself. She felt sad, and yet... she could feel Rhaego receding from her, as if he had never been.

Mirri and Jorah then described what had happened; describing the baby as "monstrous" and that he "had been dead for years"; and Dany understands that Jorah killed her son. Mirri then tells her that her son's death was the price for the spell which saved Drogo's life; not the horse's, only to discover that his life had only been preserved in its near death state, not restored.

After this, Mirri justifies herself to Dany, by saying:

> "The stallion who mounts the world will burn no cities now. His khalasar shall trample no nations into dust".

Mirri's motivation for this betrayal is clear. In my opinion she would have no reason to lie about having killed Dany's son. Her motivation was revenge for her temples being burned, and her being raped so many times.

In my mind, there is no doubt that Dany's son died as described. However, the events of what happened between Dany experiencing pain in her womb and waking up are only recounted to us by other people telling Dany; not through a character's POV chapter. Thus, there does exist a slim possibility that the baby could indeed have lived, but I think it extremely unlikely, given that Dany understands so quickly what has happened. She is never in denial or hopes that he lives; she instantly knows and accepts that he is dead. In addition, Mirri's motivation and actions are clear.

Comment: Jorah killed her son?

Comment: @SystemDown Jorah was the one who carried her into Mirri's tent.

Comment: Ah OK. I see your point of view.

Comment: @SystemDown It's not mine. =P

Comment: @SystemDown Page 633 AGOT: "Ser Jorah had killed her son, Dany knew."

Comment: Up until the past century or so, it was common practice to quietly kill babies who were malformed or unhealthy, then tell the mother that it was stillborn. I assumed that when the baby came out scaly and "monstrous", Jorah killed it for that reason.

Answer (score -1):

I think the feeling of knives inside her was an egg.(remember they have scales). I think the witch stole the egg so she could buy back what she had lost. I know this sounds insane,but considering there are dragons,elves,living dead and many other crazy things going on,why can't an egg be a part of this?We do not know how she was born. If she had a son,and it were dead,they would have burned it in a funeral fire. Fire would not have destroyed the body,as he would have her blood,and can not be destroyed by fire.

Comment: Is there support for this in the show or books?

Comment: Eggs are smooth though, not sharp. This theory is nonsense. A woman can't birth a dragon's egg in any case.

Answer (score -2):

No where in any of that does it confirm the baby died . Just taken the word of a witch that lied and/or mislead her numerous times.

And if it was disfigured or anything like that and not stillborn why would jorah kill it without consulting with his queen? Makes no sense.

I dont know if the baby is dead or not but seems to me either option has an equal chance of being correct. Idk how you could say its a very slim chance hes alive when basing your theory soley off the words of other minor charcter like who didnt like her in the first place.

And only death can pay for life but no life was giving to anyone only sustained drogo the way he already was .so maybe it could be his death payed for the life rhaego
dont kill my dreams. Lol

Comment: _"And if it was disfigured or anything like that and not stillborn why would jorah kill it without consulting with his queen? Makes no sense."_ It makes a lot of sense. As Omegacron pointed out several months ago about 200 pixels up there ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑  this was commonplace in our own world just a century or so ago. No reason to suspect it be different in Westeros or Essos.

Comment: This answer requires a tidy-up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It isn't an answer at all. It's a comment to another answer.